# jQuery duplicate select options in list

Tags: jquery

I have the following situation

```
<div class="selectContainer">
<select size="1" id="kind">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
</select>
</div>
```

<div id="second">
<ul id="test"></ul></div>

I want jQuery to automatically duplicate the option values in a list, so i will get the following HTML

```
<div id="second">
<ul id="test">
<li id="one">one</li>
<li id="two">two</li>
<li id="three">three</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I thought the following would work, but it doesn't. I gives me one list item with 'undefined' in it

```
 
$(function(){
 $("#kind").each(function () {
  li = '<li id="'+$(this).attr('value')+'">'+$(this).attr('text')+'</li>';
  $("#test").html(li);
 });
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't declare `li` without the `var` keyword unless you *want* it added to the window object (global).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are close, it should be

```
$(function(){
   $("#kind option").each(function () {
      li = '<li id="'+$(this).val()+'">'+$(this).text()+'</li>';
      $("#test").append(li);
   });
});
```

1. you need to get the options, your selector only retrieved the select element.
2. You need to use .val() and .text(). The attr won't find what you need.
3. You need to use .append(), using .html() will simply overwrite the content each time you loop through.

Comment: @Maurice You should read the comments and accept the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(function(){
    var lis = '';
    $("#kind option").each(function () {
        lis += '<li id="'+$(this).val()+'">'+$(this).text()+'</li>';
    });
    $("#test").html(lis);
});
```

You were trying to iterate over `#kind`, which is a single element, the select element. You should be iterating over options. Furthermore, you were resetting the HTML of all the `UL` every time you were iterating.

[Check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/4VKZj/)

Comment: That only gives me one list item with the value 'three'

Answer (score 1):

Another way, just for fun (plus it is both concise and efficient enough):

```
$("#test").html($("#kind > option").map(function() {
    return '<li id="' + this.value + '">' + $(this).text() + '</li>';
}).get().join(""));
```

[**Try it here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ez4Wy/)

In case it is of any interest, here is a decent discussion on normal string appends vs `Array.join()`:

- http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-fast-string-concatenation/

Comment: How is it more efficient generating an array on the fly and then joining it, compared to joining only the string? This is nothing more than a memory hog on large DOM trees.

Comment: Good question - check this out: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-fast-string-concatenation/ some interesting results in the benchmark.

Comment: That's for pure `concat vs. join`, and I see it mostly leaning towards `concat`. However, what you are doing is a double op, because you are building the array first for each `li` with `get()`, then you are joining the whole on the fly built array. See where the unnecessary op takes part?

Comment: @Shef - I do (I'm not arguing, I agree with you) I really just felt like adding to the discussion a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$("option", "#kind").each(function () {
```

instead, it looks like the select itself is being converted as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working jsfiddle: [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SuperPhil/XkV8f/)

```
$(function(){
    var li = '';
    $("#kind option").each(function () {
        li += '<li id="'+$(this).attr('value')+'">'+$(this).text()+'</li>';

    });
    $("#test").html(li);
});
```